# Notification for remove operations

Tags: notification

Is it advisable to notify a person for remove operations such as rejection, delete, removals, etc. For example, if I share to someone a document and later on if it's removed. Should it be notified to that person.

Other examples are if a person sends me a friend request and if I reject, do any notification has to be sent.

Comment: I don't know about how others seeing this question would perceive it, but for me it's not complete. Please elaborate.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean here? This isn't a specific question that can be given an answer at the moment. Can you add in some context and more details please.

Comment: For example, if I share to you a document and I remove it later.

Comment: Also consider the rejections in case of friend requests, invitation to join a group, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,simply because people like be in control of their actions and be aware of the current state of the system ([Neilson's heuristics](http://www.useit.com/papers/heuristic/heuristic_list.html)). By taking that power aware ,you are opening your system to potential issues causes by people accidently making mistakes and deleting stuff which they didn't want to.

These are the heuristics which I was referencing to :

> **Visibility of system status** The system should always keep users informed about what is going on, through appropriate feedback within
>   reasonable time.
>
> **Error prevention** Even better than good error messages is a careful design which prevents a problem from occurring in the first place.
>   Either eliminate error-prone conditions or check for them and present
>   users with a confirmation option before they commit to the action
>
> **User control and freedom** Users often choose system functions by mistake and will need a clearly marked "emergency exit" to leave the
>   unwanted state without having to go through an extended dialogue.
>   Support **undo and redo**.

Answer (score 1):

**notify and allow undo** (if possible, otherwise warn before if the operation is not reversible).

Follow [Never Use a Warning When you Mean Undo](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/neveruseawarning)

Comment: Note that I had read and answered this before the question had been changed to reveal that: the person that does the removal isn't the person to be notified but the person that was removed. In which context this answer doesn't make as much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is advisable to notify a person(or a complete team) for  any failure, success, rejection, approval in every term.
suppose you sit in an exam and you did the basic things, how will  you come to know that you are pass or fail? someone have to notify you that you score this much in the exam,

There is kind of Action and Reaction, you did something and  everyone who is concerned with the thing should be notified about the action.

if there is a mail undelivered we got an error (notification) in gmail, that the mail is not delivered to the recipient. so user is informed(notified) about the failure if gmail don't provide such notification how would user know that his mail is not delivered.

and what you have said in your comment

> For example, if I share to you a document and I remove it later.

system should notify  that the document has been removed by user, by doing this both will be informed about the action.

Comment: Internet mail delivery is "best effort", not "guaranteed delivery" - display of an error message (say, by Gmail) is only possible if the mail relay that failed delivery decides to send us a notification of the error. Not all relays do - many don't, by policy, to avoid encouraging spammers.